# Python serialization Error

Tags: python, json

When my python code trying to convert a dictionary object to Json string, it threw the following exception:

```
SerializationError: ({'status': 'rd', 
'name': 'Detecci\xf3nInt/.unclassified.ez', 'st': 0}, 
UnicodeDecodeError('utf8', 'Detecci\xf3nInt/.unclassified.ez', 7, 8, 
'invalid continuation byte'))
```

Any hints for fixing this problem please.

Comment: what version of python are you running?

Comment: python version is 2.6.6

Comment: Do you have the possibility of running python 3, because then it would likely solve your issue automagically.

Answer (score 2):

By default `json.dump()` uses UTF8 encoding, however, the value for the `name` key in your dictionary is not UTF8. It looks like one of the ISO-8859-X encodings. You can specify the encoding with the `encoding` parameter:

```
import json
d = {'status': 'rd', 'name': 'Detecci\xf3nInt/.unclassified.ez', 'st': 0}
s = json.dumps(d, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
print(s)
```

**Output**

```
{"status": "rd", "name": "Detecci\u00f3nInt/.unclassified.ez", "st": 0}
```

I had a bit of a guess as to which encoding to use, so you might want to check which is the correct encoding for your data.

Comment: I suppose UTF-8 is wider than ISO8859-1, why ISO8859-1 can support it but UTF-8 is not please?

Comment: They are not the same encodings. `u'\xf3'` is the unicode codepoint for `LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE`. When encoded as ISO-8859-1 this is the byte `'\xf3'`, but when encoded as UTF-8 it is the byte sequence `'\xc3\xb3'`.

Comment: You might want to check out [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!) by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).